# Function for a sinusoidal camel plot?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, geometry

[image]

Is this kind of function possible? If so, what would the equation look like? I can get the camel like notch with a an exponent in a sin, such as sin(x^2), but I only get one notch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are loads. Try $\sin(x)+\cos(2x)$, for instance.